# Microsoft Excel - How do I keep dd/mm/yyyy format while using CONCATENATE function?

Tags: excel, date, concatenation, string-concatenation

So I'm trying to bring together string values using the CONCATENATE function in Excel, straightforward enough it may seem. But when I try include a date (source formatting is dd/mm/yyyy) it converts to Number type data and I've no idea how to get around this.

My source data is as follows:
Cell A1: Eggs
B1: Milk
C1: Bread
D1: 08/04/2020

My formula goes as follows
`=CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1," ",C1," ",D1)`

I put spaces between each value so they're not bundled up tightly together.

I'd like for this to return **Eggs Milk Bread 08/04/2020**, but it's coming back as **Eggs Milk Bread 43929**.

Any idea why this is, and how I might resolve it?

Would be deeply grateful to anyone who can help.

Thanks.

***EDIT: Question answered below. Thanks to everyone who helped.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `TEXT(D1,"mm/dd/yyyy")` in your concatenate.

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1," ",C1," ",TEXT(D1,"dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have the most current version of Excel and have TEXTJOIN, you could use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,TEXT(A1:D1,"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

Comment: The range is A1:D1, and although it works for this instance if any of the other cells become numbers they will turn to dates.  Just an FYI, not criticism.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @Scott Craner! Also, good catch on the numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose your *Date field* inside a TEXT function like this

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1," ",C1," ",TEXT(D1,"dd/mm/yyyy"))
```